# String.format() DateTime With Arabic culture

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo, string.format

check the below code snippet,

```
namespace TestDateConvertion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime testValue = new DateTime(2013, 12, 15, 15, 33, 44);

            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
            string stringValue = string.Format(culture, "{0:d} {0:HH:mm:ss}", testValue);
            Console.WriteLine(stringValue);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It gives the output as

> 22/02/35 15:33:44

I am not getting how this is possible. whats the 35 doing in output there

Comment: Without checking, I would guess that the `ar-SA` culture is associated with the [hijri calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijri_calendar), in which december of the Gregorian year 2013 corresponds with a date in year 1435 (1435 begins in what is one of the first days of November in the Gregorian year 2013).

Comment: As culture that you set formats the date according to HijriCalendar, you got this output ... the year in your output is 1435. This is as per HijriCalendar

Comment: your code throws exception for me. `Specified time is not supported in this calendar. It should be between 04/30/1900 00:00:00 (Gregorian date) and 11/16/2077 23:59:59 (Gregorian date)` is that work for you?

Comment: what is that 13? if intended to use 2013 replace 13 with 2013

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's 13/12/2015 in Hijri, 35 means 1435 in Hijri, the default date format for Saudi Arabia.

Answer (score 1):

Is not a part of you year ?
I you try `string.Format(culture, "{0:dd MM yyyy} {0:HH:mm:ss}", testValue);`, you will receive 12 02 1435 15:33:44